# Embedded MySQL. Как сделать и использовать отдельную базу данных в папке приложения?

Tags: mysql, c, база-данных, embedded

При вызове `mysql_init()` пытается лезть в папку к базам (/var/lib/mysql) установленного пакета `mysql-server` и не может из-за прав доступа. Если сделать `su mysql`, то может, но нужно ведь не это. Мне нужна "embedded database", все причендалы которой, валяются, например, в подпапке той папки, где лежит исполняемый файл. Как этого добиться?

test.cc:

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <mysql.h>

int main()
{
    MYSQL *mysql = mysql_init(NULL);
    mysql_close(mysql);
    return 0;
}
```

и результат:

```
$ ./test
mysql_embedded: Can't find file: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql/plugin.frm' (errno: 13)
170709 23:11:46 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
170709 23:11:46 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
170709 23:11:46 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
170709 23:11:46 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
170709 23:11:46 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
170709 23:11:46 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
170709 23:11:46  InnoDB: Operating system error number 13 in a file operation.
InnoDB: The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to
InnoDB: the directory.
InnoDB: File name /var/lib/mysql/ibdata1
InnoDB: File operation call: 'create'.
InnoDB: Cannot continue operation.
```

Вот так оно компилируется:

```
g++ -I/usr/include/mysql -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -o test test.cc -lmysqld -lpthread -lz -lm -lwrap -lcrypt -ldl -laio
```

Comment: Таки да, apparmor :)

Comment: @PinkTux, я просто хочу использовать внедряемую версию MySQL (типа как SQLite), но она лезет к файлам установленного MySQL-сервера, а я совершенно не понимаю, как сделать отдельную среду с базами данных и их файлами чисто для своего приложения.

Comment: Настраивайте правила для apparmor в вашем дистрибутиве.

Comment: @PinkTux, `dpkg -l | grep -i apparmor` говорит, что у меня установлена-таки эта либа. Но как она может влиять на то, что мне нужно в данном случае? Мне нужно, чтобы в папке рядом с исполняемым файлом `test` лежала папка `db`, в которой находится все, что нужно для работы MySQL Embedded.

Comment: Apparmor запрещает (в вашем конкретном случае, при дефолтных настройках) обращаться к файлам, за которые отвечает mysqld - за пределами "стандартных" для mysqld каталогов. Нужно в конфигах apparmor разрешить это безобразие :)

Comment: @PinkTux, в моем случае это не `mysqld`, а `-lmysqld`. Большая разница. Это статическая либа встраиваемой в приложение базы MySQL. **Встраиваемой. Embedded.**

Comment: @PinkTux, не было таких сложностей с SQLite (она исходно встраиваемая), были небольшие сложности с встраиваемой версией FireBird, не было никаких сложностей с Berkeley DB с натянутым поверх нее интерфейсом SQLite усилиями Оракла. Но как использовать MySQL Embedded, я просто не понимаю. Никаких возможностей задать что-то через C API до вызова mysql_init. Остаются только переменные среды. Еще, я помню, в старых версиях MySQL был скрипт первоначальной настройки для формирования файловой среды.

Comment: @PinkTux, спасибо, я все изучил более детально, и apparmor немножко. Пришел в выводу, что действительно только баран станет использовать MySQL в качестве встраиваемой БД. Просто позарился на AIO в InnoDB, которое все равно в интерфейс никак не отображается.